# Nuxt and cloudinary - Upload images from client side directly to cloudinary

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, cloudinary

I want to upload images from my Nuxt (vue) app to Cloudinary directly (no server involved).
I couldn't find any reference to it that acutely do the work?

```
    <v-file-input
      v-else
      v-model="imageFile"
      accept="image/*"
      @change="onImageChange"
    >
    </v-file-input>
</template>
```

Java script

````
   methods: {
    this.isLoading = true;
      try {
        const response = awai UPLOAD TO CLODINARY
        this.$emit('change', response);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      } finally {
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
}

}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this Cloudinary CodePen example for HTML5 Upload.

the fact you're using Nuxt shouldn't be a problem, since this all happens after rendering anyway.

Please see this link
https://codepen.io/team/Cloudinary/pen/QgpyOK

I'm adding the actual code from the codepen

JS

```js
const cloudName = 'demo';
const unsignedUploadPreset = 'doc_codepen_example';

var fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect"),
  fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem"),
    urlSelect = document.getElementById("urlSelect");

fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (fileElem) {
    fileElem.click();
  }
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigation to "#"
}, false);

urlSelect.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  uploadFile('https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg')
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigation to "#"
}, false);


// ************************ Drag and drop ***************** //
function dragenter(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragover(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

dropbox = document.getElementById("dropbox");
dropbox.addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter, false);
dropbox.addEventListener("dragover", dragover, false);
dropbox.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);

function drop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  var dt = e.dataTransfer;
  var files = dt.files;

  handleFiles(files);
}

// *********** Upload file to Cloudinary ******************** //
function uploadFile(file) {
  var url = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloudName}/upload`;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var fd = new FormData();
  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

  // Reset the upload progress bar
   document.getElementById('progress').style.width = 0;
  
  // Update progress (can be used to show progress indicator)
  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
    var progress = Math.round((e.loaded * 100.0) / e.total);
    document.getElementById('progress').style.width = progress + "%";

    console.log(`fileuploadprogress data.loaded: ${e.loaded},
  data.total: ${e.total}`);
  });

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      // File uploaded successfully
      var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      // https://res.cloudinary.com/cloudName/image/upload/v1483481128/public_id.jpg
      var url = response.secure_url;
      // Create a thumbnail of the uploaded image, with 150px width
      var tokens = url.split('/');
      tokens.splice(-2, 0, 'w_150,c_scale');
      var img = new Image(); // HTML5 Constructor
      img.src = tokens.join('/');
      img.alt = response.public_id;
      document.getElementById('gallery').appendChild(img);
    }
  };

  fd.append('upload_preset', unsignedUploadPreset);
  fd.append('tags', 'browser_upload'); // Optional - add tag for image admin in Cloudinary
  fd.append('file', file);
  xhr.send(fd);
}

// *********** Handle selected files ******************** //
var handleFiles = function(files) {
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    uploadFile(files[i]); // call the function to upload the file
  }
};
```

HTML:

```
<div id="dropbox">
  <h1>Client-Side Upload to Cloudinary with JavaScript</h1> Learn more in this blog post - <a href="https://cloudinary.com/blog/direct_upload_made_easy_from_browser_or_mobile_app_to_the_cloud">Direct upload made easy from browser or mobile app to the cloud</a>

  <form class="my-form">
    <div class="form_line">
      <h4>Upload multiple files by clicking the link below or by dragging and dropping images onto the dashed region</h4>
      <div class="form_controls">
        <div class="upload_button_holder">
          <input type="file" id="fileElem" multiple accept="image/*" style="display:none" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
          <a href="#" id="fileSelect">Select some files</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="#" id="urlSelect">URL Upload</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress" id="progress"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="gallery" />
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, install the nuxt cloudinary pachage by visiting this link [Nuxt Cloudinary Introduction](https://cloudinary.nuxtjs.org/), then follow the setup documentation and make sure you are setup. Next, visit this link [Nuxt Cloudinary Upload](https://cloudinary.nuxtjs.org/examples/upload). That's all. Note that the later link uses uploadPreset as object key in the docs. Please change it to upload_preset so you dont get any error. Post setup code snipet below

```
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    async selectFile(e) {
      const file = e.target.files[0];

      /* Make sure file exists */
      if (!file) return;

      /* create a reader */
      const readData = (f) =>  new Promise((resolve) => {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
          reader.readAsDataURL(f);
      });

      /* Read data */
      const data = await readData(file);

      /* upload the converted data */
      const instance = this.$cloudinary.upload(data, {
        folder: 'upload-examples',
        uploadPreset: 'your-upload-preset',
      })
    }
  }  
}
</script>
```